# Can't get the for loops working

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

The first for loops it gives me the correct answer which is 0.00 as the lowest.
However when I add the second for loop for to track number of months with 0.00 rainfall, the first for loops says "nan", while the second for loops gives correct answer which is 2.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    const int NUM = 12;
    string month[NUM] =  {"JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUNE","JULY","AUG","SEPT","OCT","NOV","DEC"};
    int counter = 0;
    float lowest;
    float rainfall [NUM] = {20.75, 34.60, 0.00, 4.12, 1.00, 72.99, 3.76, 10.00,     8.09, 64.05, 0.00, 30.02};
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
        if ((rainfall[i] < rainfall [i-1]) && (rainfall[i] < lowest))
           lowest = rainfall[i];
    }
    cout << lowest << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        if (rainfall[i] == 0.00)
        counter += 1;
    }
    cout << counter;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the typing errors here;                                                     Please have a look at my code, the first for loop gives me the correct answer which is 0.00 as the lowest (when i run it alone). However when i add the second for loop to track the number of months with 0.00 rainfall, the first for loops says "nan", while the second for loops gives correct the answer which is 2. What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Initialise `lowest`:

```
float lowest=100.00;  //or any other term, like INT_MAX
```

Without initialization, you don't know what value `lowest` might hold, and therefore it will give wrong values in further calculations.

Comment: Oh!Thanks karma, after initialising lowest it works just fine.